# How to combine 2 rows in a table in one loop

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have following table and I want to use two rows in one for a loop

```
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col">All Devices</th>
                <th scope="col">Common Value</th>
                <th scope="col" *ngFor="let device of config.devices">{{device.itemName}}</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{config.data.name}}</th>
                <td>
                  <div class="example-header">
                    <mat-checkbox [ngModel]="config.data.common"></mat-checkbox>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="value" required>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td *ngFor="let device of config.devices">
                  <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="value" required>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <span *ngFor="let template of config.templates">
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="3">
                    {{template.name}}</th>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let parameter of template.parameters">
                  <th scope="row">{{parameter.name}}</th>
                  <td>
                    <div class="example-header">
                      <mat-checkbox [ngModel]="parameter.common"></mat-checkbox>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <mat-form-field>
                      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="value" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </td>
                  <td *ngFor="let device of config.devices">
                    <mat-form-field>
                      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="value" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </span>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

But it is not giving me the proper row-column structure, what I am looking for.

Can I use span (`<span *ngFor="let template of config.templates"></span>`) or any other html element or any other approach to combine row?

This is my output
[image]

Here it is stackblitz link [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zf69fk) I want all rows and column align with each other.

Comment: You have a `<span *ngFor=` in the middle of your table; you probably want to use `<tr *ngFor=` instead

Comment: Yes but I want bellow tr also the scope that loop

Comment: best possible solution would be to process JSON object (either combine 2 rows o/ column / process data) that you are passing to HTML and then you ll get final data to render in HTML

Comment: Can you share an image(you can create in excel) of expected table view that you want to display ?

Comment: @YogendraR I added output screen shot in my question Please check.

Comment: Is this the expected view, if not, share the expected one.
And also create a minimal stackblitz.

Comment: No not yet I tried ng-container as well it is giving template parse error.

Comment: where are you getting template parse error, the stackblitz, I shared in answer has no such error. (At least acknowledge in the comment, when someone answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `span` with `ng-container`

check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9rvhnx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)